# Uploading a file to a different directory on server

Tags: php

I am using PHP to allow users to upload photos on my web app.

I am using the PHP function:

```
move_uploaded_file();
```

And I define the upload path:

```
define('UPLOADPATH', 'images/');
```

To place the photo in my  *images/*  directory

Now I want to give users the ability to do the same thing, from a sub domain of my website.

Do I do:

```
define('UPLOADPATH', 'http:/mobile.website.com/images/');
```

If so, how do I prevent others from uploading malicious files to my server, from their server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Second argument of `move_uploaded_file()` should be a directory, not a URL,

I mean  this is correct :

```
define('UPLOADPATH', 'mobile/images/');
move_uploaded_file($tmp,UPLOADPATH.$name);
```

but this is not :

```
define('UPLOADPATH', 'http:/mobile.website.com/images/');
move_uploaded_file($tmp,UPLOADPATH.$name);
```

Second of all, for preventing others from uploading malicious files to your server, you better check the extension of file.

Comment: I always do, I am not going to post all of my code on here.

Comment: so what do you mean from  `prevent others from uploading malicious files to my server`

Comment: I mean would anyone be able to use a URL as an upload path, to move THEIR uploaded files on THEIR website, to my images/ directory on my server? Or does move_uploaded_file() not accept URLs?